# Benth: Risk-neutral measure in incomplete markets

Tags: option-pricing, derivatives, risk-neutral-measure, girsanov

I am currently working on Benth and Benth ["THE VOLATILITY OF TEMPERATURE AND PRICING OF WEATHER
DERIVATIVES"](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/10566/pm12-05.pdf?sequence=1) and i am stuck at following paragraph at page 10, which is about risk-neutral measures in incomplete markets of weather derivatives:

> "In order to derive a more explicit expression for the futures price, we need to specify
> the risk-neutral probability $Q$. Since temperature is not a storable commodity, the futures
> contracts can not be hedged and the market is therefore incomplete. A risk-neutral probability is by definition a probability measure $Q\sim P$ such that all tradeable assets in the
> market are martingales after discounting. Thus, all equivalent probabilities $Q$ will become
> risk-neutral probabilities. We specify a sub-family of probability measures $Q$ using the
> Girsanov transform: [...]"

**Problem:**
I do not understand why all equivalent probabilities are risk-neutral probabilities in incomplete markets?!

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That is my solution:

> The price of weather derivatives cannot simply be calculated using a hedging strategy, since the underlying is not tradable. We are therefore in an incomplete market. If we restrict the market to weather derivatives, the treasury bill with a risk-free interest rate $r\in\mathbb{R}$ is the only tradeable asset in the market. The discounted treasury bill price is $1$ and it is therefore a trivial martingale with respect to all equivalent measures. Thus, all equivalent probability measures $\mathcal{Q}\sim \mathcal{P}$ will become risk neutral probabilities.